# Address formatting based on locale in android

Tags: android, street-address

Hi in my application i need to display the input address according to the locale set by the user. Has anyone worked or address formatting or has any pointers wrt it in Android platform.

Comment: Can i know the reason for -1 ratings for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [googlei18n/libaddressinput: Google’s postal address library, powering Android and Chromium](https://github.com/googlei18n/libaddressinput). There are two modules in the project :android and :common. You should only need :common to format the address for locale aware display.

```
import android.location.Address;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import com.google.i18n.addressinput.common.AddressData;
import com.google.i18n.addressinput.common.FormOptions;
import com.google.i18n.addressinput.common.FormatInterpreter;
...
public static String getFormattedAddress(@NonNull final Address address, 
                                         @NonNull final String regionCode) {
    final FormatInterpreter formatInterpreter
            = new FormatInterpreter(new FormOptions().createSnapshot());
    final AddressData addressData = (new AddressData.Builder()
            .setAddress(address.getThoroughfare())
            .setLocality(address.getLocality())
            .setAdminArea(address.getAdminArea())
            .setPostalCode(address.getPostalCode())
            .setCountry(regionCode) // REQUIRED
            .build());
    // Fetch the address lines using getEnvelopeAddress,
    List<String> addressFragments = formatInterpreter.getEnvelopeAddress(addressData);
    // join them, and send them to the thread.
    return TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
            addressFragments);
}
```

NOTE: regionCode must be a valid iso2 country code, because this is where the format interpreter pulls the address format from. (See [RegionDataConstants](https://github.com/googlei18n/libaddressinput/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/google/i18n/addressinput/common/RegionDataConstants.java) for the list of formats, if you're curious.)

> Sets the 2-letter CLDR region code of the address; see
>   AddressData#getPostalCountry(). Unlike other values passed to the
>   builder, the region code can never be null.

Example: US

> 801 CHESTNUT ST
>   
> ST. LOUIS, MO 63101

Example: JP

> 〒1600023
>   
> NISHISHINJUKU
>   
> 3-2-11 NISHISHINJUKU SHINJUKU-KU TOKYO

Comment: I've been searching for this kind of library, thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

I've done a fair bit of localization on other platforms.  Here's a guide to localization for Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework

One approach would be to use localized resources to store MessageFormat strings that correspond to the Address layout for each locale you want.  From there, you'll need a reference to the global address block standards and create the format strings for each locale you need.

Comment: Thanks, i am referring the same android localization it does has Address API but no formatting of address is provided based on the locale selected.

Comment: I think the reasoning is that an already entered postal address "belongs" to a locale and has a fixed way of formatting it. It doesn't make much sense for example to express a US postal address by German conventions or the other way around. If you are accessing the ContactsContract database then just use the formatted address field of the StructuredPostal entity.

Comment: In this [Google example code](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html) they format an address line using an idea similar to my suggestion.  Not sure if there is an easier way.